# Macbook pro displayport VGA not recognised unless I plug it in again

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display, monitor, macbook

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 on a macbook pro 5.1.

The external monitor, connected to the display port adaptor(vga) is not recognised during the start up.

However, if I unplug it and plug it in again after the Nvidia driver has started then it is recognised.

Is there a way to get this to work without unplugging and plugging it in again???

Comment: (SOLVED) I bought a MACALLY "MINI DISPLAYPORT TO HDMI/VGA/DVI 4K ADAPTER. Connnected it to the MacBook Pro and used the HDMI Connection Port to my monitor. As soon as the Nvidia module loaded I had full 1920x1080 resolution on my external monitor.